# Regular expression for strings with an even number of zeroes and ones

Tags: regex

What is a regular expression for strings of 0 and 1 with an even number of zeros and an even number of ones?

I have something like `(1*01*01*)*(0*10*10*)*`.

Does it look good?

Comment: It could just be me, but that question doesn't make sense to me completely.  Maybe rephrase?

Comment: hey listen mate/....i am just asking whether what i have done is right or not..and if u dont want to help then dont.....

Comment: "nice guy": No need for a rude response to someone who **was** trying to help by pointing out that your question was unclear.  (And if that's "nice", I'd hate to meet "Kevinmeanguy"...)

Comment: I suspect this is a homework question. No-one in their right mind would prefer a heinous regex over a simple "count the characters" approach which is both easier to understand and doesn't run the performance risk of backtracking.

Comment: @Dave: I think @Kevin was responding to a different comment, that was later deleted. I'd hate to see that start a downvote/close vote storm...

Comment: Another option is to use a [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for eg checking even amount of `0`s and on success match even amount of `1`s which is not necessarily slower: [`^(?=1*(?:01*01*)*$)0*(?:10*10*)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/4n3EMn/1)

Answer (score 15):

Well, this is probably homework, but what the heck:

```
^(00|11|(01|10)(00|11)*(01|10))*$
```

Edit: simplified!

Comment: +1: Nice work. For anybody wants to try this out interactively, try http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: @tloflin: Did you use JFLAP? I did and it gave exactly the same answer :)

Comment: @tiftik, haha no, I used Notepad. But I did start with a DFSM and reduced it, so I'm not surprised.

Comment: @Ibrahim: Sure it does, note the `*` at the end of the expression. It would be broken into 1010 and 0110, both of which match the expression in parentheses.

Answer (score 6):

1100 is in the language, but doesn't match your expression.  10101 is not in the language,
but your expression matches it.

I'd suggest starting by drawing a DFA.  There's a pretty obvious 4-state machine that recognizes this language.  (Is it possible to do better?) The empty string is in the language, so the start state is an accepting state. Are there other accepting states? For a non-accepting state S, is
there a prefix that takes you from start->S?  Is there a way to loop from S back to S without hitting an accepting state?  Is there suffix that takes you from S back to an accepting state?

Answer (score 1):

A counterexample for your given regular expression is `01010101`.

<strike>You may find that writing a regular expression for this *particular* problem is not going to be possible (unless you use some *non-regular* extensions to the usual regular expression language).</strike>

As mentioned by Jim Lewis below, this should indeed be a solvable problem.

Comment: The set of all strings over {0,1} with an even number of 0's and an even number of 1's is most certainly regular. A DFA with four states should suffice.

Comment: @Jim Lewis: Thanks, on further consideration you're quite right.

Comment: I've often wondered why people strike out stuff that they later discover they disagree with. I tend to just delete it and rephrase the answer. It appears to me that the strikeout adds no value to the final answer, and our "education" can be seen in the history if anyone's interested anyway. Just curious since I've seen quite a few people do it.

Comment: @Pax: If the edit is in response to a comment, doing it as a strikethrough leaves enough context for the comment to still make sense.

Comment: @paxdiablo: Perhaps I was thinking that an edited answer would cause Jim's comment to no longer make sense, and I wanted to provide the context for that. Also, it reminds future readers that even those with high rep who have been around for a while are not infallible. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
@tmp = $str =~ /0/g;

print scalar @tmp % 2 == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd';
```

Comment: This is not a regular expression. This is a program.