# Regular expression for even number of 0's and even number of 1's

Tags: regex

I was trying to make regular expression for the strings that accept even number of `0's` and even number of `1's`. But I was not able to do so. Please any one can help?

I tried making

```
(0000+0011+0101+0110+1111+1100+1010+1001)*(^+00+11)
```

but it does not accept the string `100001`.

I read that question that **@vks** has addressed but was not able to understand the answers properly. I tried to add a comment but my rep is below 50, so am not able to do that, that's why I asked a new question.

Comment: count the no of 0s.they are 4 and 4 is an even no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?![^0\n]*0[^0\n]*(?:0[^0\n]*0)*[^0\n]*$)(?![^1\n]*1[^1\n]*(?:1[^1\n]*1)*[^1\n]*$)[10]*$
```

This will match only string with `even no of 0's and 1's`.This uses `lookahead` so for long string it will take time.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/iS6jF6/11

Comment: i dont understand these symbols like ? ^ etc.
I use only + and * in my regular expression .
i dont know about any other symbol please explian other symbol

Comment: @slvi check the link.On the right sidde you can see all the explanations

Comment: i am still not able to understand.i dont know anything about these lookaheads etc.i make simple regex and i dont know anything about using new line etc

Comment: @slvi you can simpy use `^(00|11|(01|10)(00|11)*(01|10))*$` without lookaheads

Comment: no.I am not able to understand thes symbols ^,| and $.can you give an explaination what these symbols do?

Comment: `^`===starting of string,`|` is alternation operator ie `A|B` mean either `A` or `B`.`$` is end of string.

Comment: Asking the same question twice is a good way to get an answer ^ ^

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen we both r trolled :P

Comment: thankew.now i got it.actually i use + instead of | that was why i was not able to understand.now i got it :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple regular expression which will match an even number of zeroes or ones:

```
^(00|11|(01|10)(00|11)*(01|10))*$
```

This was tested on the site [Regular Expressions 101](https://regex101.com/).

Comment: There is serious problem on this site with newer users not making any effort to search the already existing SO database, q.v. [this answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725522/regular-expression-for-strings-with-an-even-number-of-zeroes-and-ones) to essentially the same question.

Comment: Thanx...have marked this duplicate!!!!!!!!

Comment: i have edited my question.and one more problem is there,that we new users cannot comment on the existing questions if we have a confusion.

Comment: and i am not able to understand this regex.can it be made using only + and *?

Comment: You would not really want to use the + operator in my solution, because that would mean allowing something to occur 0 **or** 1 times.  We are trying to match only an even number of 0s or 1s, hence the pairs of 0s and 1s which you see in the regex.

Comment: actually the problem is that i am not able to understand what this ^,| and $ sign holds for.I dont know their functioning.

Comment: `^` means the **start** of the string and `$` means the end of the string.